# Parsing a dynamic key JSON array using Android retrofit

Tags: android, json, parsing, retrofit

How to consume this JSON using Android retrofit?

```
{
"Pepsico": {
    "items": [
        {
            "pro_name": "Lays indian mGic masala",
            "pro_price": "0"
        },
        {
            "pro_name": "amla hair amla",
            "pro_price": "0"
        }
    ]
},
"Amul": {
    "items": [
        {
            "pro_name": "Amul butter",
            "pro_price": "48"
        },
        {
            "pro_name": "Amul cow ghee",
            "pro_price": "270"
        },
        {
            "pro_name": "Amul Kool Elaine flavored milk",
            "pro_price": "20"
        },
        {
            "pro_name": "Amul plain cheese slices",
            "pro_price": "122"
        },
        {
            "pro_name": "pure ghee",
            "pro_price": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

The expected output should be in a nested recycler view:

```
Category Name 1
Product1
Product2
Product3
Category Name 2
Product4
Product5
Product6
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following code.

```
//if your product(Pepsico,Amul...etc) is also dynamic than you can parse you api response in hashmap dynamically
 HashMap<String,Product>()

//if your product is fixed then you should use this approach
class ApiResult{
Product Pepsico;
Product Amul;

public Product getPepsico() {
    return Pepsico;
}

public void setPepsico(Product pepsico) {
    Pepsico = pepsico;
}

public Product getAmul() {
    return Amul;
}

public void setAmul(Product amul) {
    Amul = amul;
}
}


class  Product{
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> items;

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getItems() {
    return items;
}

public void setItems(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> items) {
    this.items = items;
}
}
```

Comment: The products are also dynamic from API

Comment: then you should go with first approach, directly serialize your response in hasmap